# How to monitor processes that accessed a particular file?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, fuser

i know there's a fuser command that lists out pids of processes, but how do you continuously monitor what process accessed the file? (think behavior similar to tail -f filename)

say there's a process which writes to a file and releases the handle at some interval, so it's hard to catch that process using fuser.

Comment: Please check http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify

Comment: How (non-)intrusive and (non-)interactive do you need/can afford this to be?  @cravoori's polling could work if the interval you mention is long enough; replacing the file with a named pipe and saturating its buffer will block all writers so you can identify them at leisure but may not be the kind of solution you're looking for; finally, you can define your own Linux [kernel tracepoints](http://netsplit.com/2011/03/07/tracing-on-linux/) to trace which process opened a particular file for writing.

Answer (score 1):

you could watch to execute commands at periodic intervals. Watch also supports a differences flag for purposes of highlighting differences on consecutive runs

```
watch -n 5  'fuser file_name'
```

Comment: not really working for me... the writes to the file are pretty brief and using watch didn't catch it (tried watch -n 1 as well)

Answer (score 0):

You could use inotifywatch, assuming you are on a Linux.

This command will print all access and modifies on a file for 60 seconds, then prints out stats.

```
inotifywatch -v -e access -e modify -t 60 filename
```

You can get inotifywatch's source as https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki

Comment: This will show the number of accesses / modifications, but is there a way to find out *which process* accessed / modified the file?